# how to group oracle queries which has aggregate functions

Tags: oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

**it says "not a groupby function". when I add D.unitpricef to groupby it doesn't show any error,but  in result it shows  same itmcode multiple time. one item code should diplay only one time**

```
SELECT 
    ItemCode, 
    case when H.InvoType = 1 then concat(ItemCode,' ( SLT Equipment )' ) else concat(ItemCode,' ( 
  CONBES Eqipment )' ) end as EquName,
    case when TRIM(SUM(QTY)) is null then ''  else TRIM(TO_CHAR(SUM(QTY),'999999')) end as QTY,
     CAST( (SUM(QTY) * D.unitpricef) AS NUMBER(38,2)) AS Amount
    FROM Invoicedetails D 
    INNER JOIN  
    invoiceheader H ON D.InvoiceNo = H.InvoiceNo 
    INNER JOIN Equipment E ON E.EquCode = ItemCode
    WHERE 
    H.CancelStat= 0 
    AND H.ReceiptStat = 1  
    AND H.BCCODE = 'xxx'
    GROUP BY ItemCode,H.InvoType ORDER BY ItemCode ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `group by` using the same expressions associated to the aggregate function

```
SELECT 
    ItemCode, 
    case when H.InvoType = 1 then concat(ItemCode,' ( SLT Equipment )' ) else concat(ItemCode,' ( CONBES Eqipment )' ) end as EquName,
    case when TRIM(SUM(QTY)) is null then ''  else TRIM(TO_CHAR(SUM(QTY),'999999')) end as QTY,
    CAST( (SUM(QTY) * D.unitpricef) AS NUMBER(38,2)) AS Amount
    FROM Invoicedetails D 
    INNER JOIN  
    invoiceheader H ON D.InvoiceNo = H.InvoiceNo 
    INNER JOIN Equipment E ON E.EquCode = ItemCode
    WHERE 
    H.CancelStat= 0 
    AND H.ReceiptStat = 1  
    AND H.BCCODE = 'xxx'
    GROUP BY 
    ItemCode
    case when H.InvoType = 1 then concat(ItemCode,' ( SLT Equipment )' ) else concat(ItemCode,' ( CONBES Eqipment )' ) end 
  
    ORDER BY ItemCode ASC;
```

Comment: I dont think `case when TRIM(SUM(QTY)) is null then ''  else TRIM(TO_CHAR(SUM(QTY),'999999')) end` should come under group by clause.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, you are totally right. Typo error when copy & paste ;) thank you